# Apps made with android studio 2.1.2 is very very slow while opening

Tags: android, android-studio

So it may sound a bit weird but I am having a problem in android studio 2.1.2.

I used to work on android studio 1.5, and the apps which I made worked fine, but now with this android studio 2.1.2 the apps are very slow.

It is taking quite a lot of time to appear on the screen even a blank activity having a toolbar, fab.

So can anyone suggest what the problem could be? Keep in mind that phone is absolutely fine. I tested with other phones also.

Comment: Try to re-install `USB Drivers`.

Comment: Try disabling the Instant Run first.

Comment: If you run the app without AS, will it run against your wishes?

Comment: Well i meant that only even if i run the app which has been coded in the as2.1.2 it takes quite a bit of time to open